# With npm, how to update a core dependency?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, webpack

A core js dependency, like babel, or webpack, or react, or angular, commonly have many dependents. E.g. a webpack build can easily have a dozen loaders and plugins; an app using react may have a dozen react widgets. Upgrading webpack requires finding versions of all of the loaders and plugins that work with the new version of webpack.

But npm dependency resolution works in the other direction. Installing one widget will install one version of react; installing a second widget will install another, possibly different version of react, etc. Npm doesn't install a set of widget versions that all depend on the same version of react, which is what's required to make something that works.

Is there any way to do this without manually discovering appropriate versions for every dependent? This is particularly problematic with webpack, since updated loaders can require updating other core libraries (babel, cssnext, react), which will then require updates of all *their* dependents. This quickly becomes many dozens of packages, each of which has to be manually investigated.

Comment: You shouldn't need to manually deal with anything like this; npm (or yarn) should load various compatible versions into an appropriate optimal tree. Sure, you may end up with different versions of the same library in various node_modules subdirectories, but that's how it goes.

Comment: I think you're trying to describe *peer dependencies*, which NPM does have. For example, a React-related package that relies on hooks can say that it needs to be installed alongside React >= 16.8. They won't each is fall their own React.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Then the question is, if there are a dozen react-related packages with peer dependency of react 15, and I need to update to react 16, what command will update all of those react-related packages to something that works with react 16?

Comment: They may not all have versions that work with React 16, or they may all already work with everything above 15, or a mix. You'll get warnings from NPM about any conflicts when you upgrade React. But the best answer is a good coverage of automated tests, so you can run them to find out if the things you care about still work.

Comment: yeah, that's the process I described. It's extremely laborious, and expensive.